# Probability --- segments

Tags: geometric-probability

- Inside a line segment $E$ with length $6$ unit, there are $2$ segments $A$ with length $2$ unit and $B$ with length $3$ unit.
- The  position of  $A$  is fixed  with  its  left  end  being  $k$  unit  from  the  left  end  of  $E$. Thus  the  distance  between  their  right  ends  will  be $\left(\,4 - k\,\right)$ unit,while  $B$  can  move  freely  and  uniformly  inside  $E$.
- If  a  point  is  chosen  randomly  on  $E$ , find  the  probability  that  the  point  lies  inside  $A$  and  $B$  at  the  same  time.

Comment: This problem is somewhat different from the usual ones, so it would sad if it were closed because you have not mentioned what you have tried. Please do so, by editing the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take left-hand end to have coordinate 0 and right-hand end to have coordinate 6. Let $b$ be the coordinate of the left-hand end of $B$. So $b$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,3]$.

Let the point $X$ have coordinate $x$, so $x$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,6]$.

$X\in B$ iff $x\in[b,b+3]$, and $X\in A$ iff $x\in[k,k+2]$. So for $b\in[-3,k-3]$ we have $A\cap B=\emptyset$. For $b\in[k-3,k-1]$ we have $A\cap B=[k,b+3]$. For $b\in[k-1,k]$ we have $A\cap B=A$. For $b\in[k,k+2]$ we have $A\cap B=[b,k+2]$ and for $b\in[k+2,6]$ we have $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Case 1: $k<1$. $18p(x\in A\cap B)=\int_0^k2\ db+\int_k^{k+2}(k+2-b)\ db=2(k+1)$.

Case 2: $1\le k<3$. $18p(x\in A\cap B)=\int_0^{k-1}(b+3-k)db+\int_{k-1}^k2\ db+\int_k^3(k+2-b)db=-k^2+4k+1$

Case 3: $3<k\le4$. $18p(x\in A\cap B)=\int_{k-3}^{k-1}(b+3-k)db+\int_{k-1}^32\ db=2+8-2k=10-2k$

[image]

$\textbf{Comment}$

Piecewise functions are fiddly and it is easy to make mistakes. So one needs to do some basic checking. (1) Is the result continuous? (Answer: yes), (2) Does the graph look plausible (no obvious odd wiggles etc) (Answer: yes), (3) Does it respect any obvious symmetries in the problem? (The obvious symmetry here is that the probability should be the same for $k=2\pm h$, which it is.)

Comment: Thanks  again . But , sorry ! May  be  I  have not  mentioned  clear  enough . For  the  statement  "  B  can move freely and uniformly inside  E ." I  have  assumed  that  the  whole  segment  of  B  must  stay  inside E (fully) , no  part  of  B  can  exceed  ( outside ) both  ends  of  E . I  apologize  for  my  carelessness !

Comment: Does  your  graph  show  that  when  k = 0  then  P  will  be  about  1/9 = 0.11  and  when k = 2  then  P  will be at  its  maximum  value  of  about  0.28 ?  What  will  be  the  average  value  of  P  ? What  will  be  the  values  of  k  for  a  P  of  0.25 ?

Comment: @mrwong Look at the formulae above the graph. Yes, the prob is $\frac{1}{9}$ for $k=0$. Yes, the maximum is at $k=2$ with value $\frac{5}{18}\approx0.27778$. To get the average value of the prob you have to integrate assuming $k$ is equally likely to have any value in $[0,4]$. That gives $\frac{23}{108}\approx 0.2130$. The prob is 0.25 for $k$ satisfying $2k^2-8k+7=0$ which gives $k=2\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\approx$1.2929 or 2.7071.

Comment: Welcome to join the discussion of this type of problem in www.mathisfunforum.com if you are interested !